# Update and flashdata message not working on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I've been working on a new CodeIgniter application and so far I've been able to create "page_categories" into the table, now my problem is when I try to update a certain category.

Let's say that I have two records on page_categories table:

[image]

Ok, now to be more specific when I try to change the name of "Page Category Two" rather than changing that name, my form updates the first record "Page Category One". Any idea how to fix this?

This is what I have on my controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        // Get Current Subject
        $data['item'] = $this->Pages_categories_model->get($id);

        // Load template
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'pages_categories/edit', $data);
    } else {
        $old_name = $this->Pages_categories_model->get($id)->name;
        $new_name = $this->input->post('name');

        // Create Post Array
        $data = array(
            'name'  => $this->input->post('name')
        );

        // Insert Subject
        $this->Pages_categories_model->update($id, $data);

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id'   => $this->db->insert_id(),
            'type'          => 'subject',
            'action'        => 'updated',
            'user_id'       => 1,
            'message'       => 'A page category ('.$old_name.') was renamed to ('.$new_name.')'
        );

        // Insert Activity
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Page category has been updated');

        //Redirect
        redirect('admin/pages_categories');
    }
}
```

and this is what I have on my model:

```
<?php
class Pages_categories_model extends CI_MODEL{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'pages_categories';
    }

    public function get_list(){
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function get($id){
        $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $query->row();
    }

    public function add($data){
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function update($id, $data){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }
}
```

and finally my view:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Edit Page Category</h2>

<?php echo form_open('admin/pages_categories/edit/'.$item->id); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Page Category Name', 'name'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'id'    => 'name',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->name,
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Update Page Category', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I would like to say that my flash data message is not working as I expected. (It's not that important though.)

I want the flash-data message to be displayed in a different view; here it is my view:

```html
<h2 class="page-header">Page Categories</h2>
<?php $CI =& get_instance(); if($CI->session->flashdata('success'){ ?>
           <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Success!! </strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
           </div>
     <?php } ?>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')) : ?>
 <?php echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'.$this->session->flashdata('error').'</div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>




<?php if($subjects) : ?>
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Date Created</th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <?php foreach($subjects as $subject) : ?>
 <?php $date = strtotime($subject->create_date); ?>
 <?php $formatted_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $date); ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $subject->id; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $subject->name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $formatted_date; ?></th>
   <td>
    <?php echo anchor('admin/pages_categories/edit/'.$subject->id.'', 'Edit', 'class="btn btn-default"'); ?>
    <?php echo anchor('admin/pages_categories/delete/'.$subject->id.'', 'Delete', 'class="btn btn-danger"'); ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php else : ?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">No Page Category Found</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the where clause before the query in this code in your model

```
public function get($id){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);  // Give where clause before query
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

    return $query->row();
}
```

**EDIT: Adding answer for flashdata**

Well, for flashdata, You have to call `$_SESSION` directly. Source: [codeigniter documentation here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)

so instead of

```
<?php $CI =& get_instance(); if($CI->session->flashdata('success'){ ?>
```

write

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['success']) { ?>
```

Comment: Glad to know that. Please accept as answer if  it solves your issue.

Comment: @Kevin, just share the output of `<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried echoing the `$id` in the controller? Your code doesn't seem like having any problem.

About flash data, you are not using it anywhere in the view. That's why it is not getting displayed.

```
<?php $CI =& get_instance(); if($CI->session->flashdata('success'){ ?>
           <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Success!! </strong><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
           </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

This will work fine.

Comment: I have tried your code for the flash data and yet I see no difference :/ .I want the flashdata messages in a different view

Comment: I want the flashdata messages in a different view, here it is:
``

Comment: Then you have not autoloaded the session in config/autoload.php file I guess. Please check.

Comment: Flash data will be displayed in the very next view. So it should work.

Comment: I updated my question, you can check my code.(again is  in a different view)

Comment: Try adding refresh in `redirect('admin/pages_categories','refresh');` May this can help you. If that doesn't work try $this->session->keep_flashdata()